# How to show custom error page on uWSGI

Tags: cgi, uwsgi

How to create custom error (CGI or HTML) using uWSGI application server?

Example configuration taken from https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3951/2719

How to execute a CGI script (or just a HTML file if not possible) when user visited link that doesn't exists, instead of just `Not Found` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the internal routing subsystem:

error-route-status = 404 static:yourfile.html

or

error-route-status = 404 cgi:yourscript.foo

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/InternalRouting.html